# Selenium Web Driver - login event not launching

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm using Selenium Web driver for testing, but can't ecen get past login page. The code I'm using:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "URL");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginForm:username")).SendKeys("uName");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginForm:password")).SendKeys("pass");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginForm:login")).Click();
```

Element locators are correct and login click is happening, but after that I am not logged in, but page is just stuck there - no error or something. Same code worked in IDE.

I'm using IE9 and also there is changed settings:

```
 var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
            options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

Any advices how to overcome this problem?

Comment: What drivers have you tried? Have you tried different locators for the elements? What happens if you try the same thing in the IDE?

Comment: I'm using InternetExplorerDriver with specified options. I tried different locators, but as I said - button click is happening, but after that - no login event. So I believe problem is somewhere else. In IDE this is working

Comment: IDE is in firefox. Did you try with firefoxDriver and see whether the issue is specific to IEDriver?

Answer (score 1):

This happens with me very often, but not sure if it is the same reason for you.

When you run the tests locally, all the actions (`sendkeys`, `click` etc) take place really quickly. The `loginForm:login` button could be kept disabled until the user enters text in fields `loginForm:username` and `loginForm:password`. So there is a possibility that the button `loginForm:login` could have not been active when it is being clicked.

So I would recommend using an explicit wait to check if the element id `loginForm:login` is displayed before clicking it.
*This step is basically useless but all it does is simply waste some time between "sending keys" to the password text box field and clicking submit.*

Also for a quick check you could also do something similar to `sleep 2` (make the script sleep for 2 seconds) after entering the password and before clicking the login button.

IF you eventually plan to run this on a remote machine, you dont need to do any of the above two steps, the time delay due to communication between the machines will be sufficient for the whole process to work smoothly.

(The same problem occurs on the linkedin login page-  Login button is disabled unless Username and password is entered, but the speed at which the webdriver performs each step, The login button is not active when being clicked on.)